# how can I open my garage door?

Tags: doors, garage

Someone copped my garage key during a visit & I am alarmed. I can't access it from inside due to an 'overstuffed' garage (I am 68 yrs old & don't want to take a tumble) How can I get my door open? The spare key will not turn the lock.

Comment: A locksmith will be able to help you. Giving advise on how to break into a garage, is not the type of thing we like to do around here ( even if you really are an elderly gentleperson).

Comment: And if the key is AWOL you probably want that lock rekeyed in any case (or a new cylinder, whichever.)